# Трансформирование объекта

Tags: css

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добиться такого эффекта (см. на картинке)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: simple & stupid: В редакторе прошелся бы по картинке белой краской)